# Laravel Fogot password not working - Invalid Token

Tags: laravel-8

I tried to implement forgot password functionality and it's sending email correctly but when trying to rest the password its shows an invalid token even though I tested the token manually with Hash::check() which returns true.

Forgot Password Email Sender:

```
$status = Password::sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );

return $status == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
       ? redirect()->route('success', 'forgot-password')->with(['status' => __($status)])
       : back()->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
```

Reset Password Receiver:

```
$status = Password::reset(
        $request->only('email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'),
        function ($user, $password) {
            $user->forceFill([
                'password' => Hash::make($password),
            ]);

            $user->save();

            event(new PasswordReset($user));
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, It's my mistake when I created the table to hold the token and email I made created_at as date so only the created date is held on it so the token will be always invalid.

Solution: created_at should be either dateTime or timestamp.(So it can hold the time too)